# JavaScript sort/pointer arrows now showing up in any browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I only added the JS files to this post, but this assignment is a report table that is sorted using JS. Somehow the arrow/sorters are not showing up in any browser. This assignment is due later tonight and I spent hours trying to sort out issues. I thought you can code the sort/arrows using JS, but somehow they are showing up as broken links/images. It is supposed to look like this:[image]

```js
//Create a new object called TableSort that takes two parameters: tableId and lastRow 
var TableSort = function ( tableId, lastRow ) {
    //the value of the variable that is this
 var that = this;
 //if less than 2 arguments are passed to the TableSort object
 if ( arguments.length < 2) {
  //the value of lastRow is true
  lastRow = true;
 }
 
    //the value of the table property of the the TableSort object is the value of the id element represented by the value of tableId
    this.table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    
 //if the table parameter exists and it does not have a node type of 1
    if ( this.table && this.table.nodeType != 1 ) {
        //throw a new error that says "TableSort: Table id is not a DOM element."
  throw new Error("TableSort: Table id is not a DOM element.");
    }
    //if the tagname property of the table property is not TABLE
 if ( this.table.tagName != "TABLE" ) {
        //throw a new error that says "TableSort: Table id is not a table element."
  throw new Error("TableSort: Table id is not a table element.");
    }

    //the value of the sortColumn property of the TableSort object is an empty string
    this.sortColumn = "";
    //the value of the sortUp property of the TableSort object is true
 this.sortUp = true;
    //the value of the imageNodes property of the TableSort object is an empty array
 this.imageNodes = [];
 //the value of the lastRow property of the TableSort object is the value of lastRow
 this.lastRow = lastRow;

    //the value of the variable headers is an array of the th tags in the table 
    var headers = this.table.getElementsByTagName("th");

    //create variables called header, columnName, imageNode, and imageClick
    var header, columnName, imageNode, imageClick;
    //create a for loop where the variable i is equal to 0, it continues to run while the value of i is less than the length of the headers array, and i increments by one on each loop
 for ( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        //the value of header is the item in the headers array represented by i
  header = headers[i];
        
        //the value of imageNode is a new "img" element
        imageNode = document.createElement("img");
        
        //the value of columnName is the className property of header
        columnName = header.className;
        //if i equals 0
  if ( i == 0 ) {
            //the value of the sortColumn property of the TableSort object is the value of columnName
   this.sortColumn = columnName;
            //the src property of imageNode is "arrows_up.png"
   imageNode.src = "arrows_up.png";
        //otherwise
  } else {
            //the src property of imageNode is "arrows_off.png"
   imageNode.src = "arrows_off.png";
        }

        //the value of imageClick is the imageClickHandler method of the TableSort object with the parameter of columnName
        imageClick = this.imageClickHandler(columnName);
        
        //execute the add method of the jsLib event object with the parameters of imageNode, "click", and imageClick
        jsLib.event.add(imageNode, "click", imageClick);
        
        //execute the appendChild method of header with a parameter of imageNode
        header.appendChild(imageNode);
        //the value of the columnName item in the imageNodes array property of the TableSort object is the value of imageNode
  this.imageNodes[columnName] = imageNode;
    }
    
    //execute the sort method of the TableSort object
    this.sort();
}

//the imageClickHandler metho of the TableSort object is a function with one parameter: columnName
TableSort.prototype.imageClickHandler = function (columnName) {
    //the value of the variable that is this
 var that = this;
    
    //return the following function
    return function () {
        //if the sortColumn property of that equals the value of columnName
        if ( that.sortColumn == columnName ) {
            //toggle the sortUp property of the that object
   that.sortUp = ! that.sortUp;
        // otherwise
        } else {
            //the src property of the that.sortColumn item in the imageNodes array is "arrows_off.png"
            that.imageNodes[that.sortColumn].src = "arrows_off.png";
            
            //the value of the sortColumn property of that is the value of ColumnName
            that.sortColumn = columnName;
            //the value of the sortUp property of the that object is true
   that.sortUp = true;
        }
        
        //if the sortUp property of that has a value of true
        if ( that.sortUp ) {
            //the src property of the that.sortColumn item in the imageNodes array is "arrows_up.png"
   that.imageNodes[that.sortColumn].src = "arrows_up.png";
        } else {
            //the src property of the that.sortColumn item in the imageNodes array is "arrows_down.png"
   that.imageNodes[that.sortColumn].src = "arrows_down.png";
        }
  //execute the sort method of the that object
        that.sort();
    }
}

//the sort method of the TableSort object is defined as
TableSort.prototype.sort = function () {
    //the value of the variable that is this
 var that = this;
    //if the sortColumn property of the TableSort object is an empty string, return to the calling function
 if ( this.sortColumn == "" ) return;

    //the value of the variable rowNodes is an array of the tr tags in the table
    var rowNodes = this.table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    //if the length of the rowNodes array is equal to or less than 1, return to the calling function
 if (rowNodes.length <= 1 ) return;

    //the value of the variable rows is an empty array
    var rows = [];
    //create a for loop where i equals zero, the for loop runs as long as the value of i is less than the length of the rowNodes array, and i increments by 1 each time
 for ( var i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++) {
        //add the item in the rowNodes array represented by the number i to the end of the rows array.
  rows.push( rowNodes[i] );
    }

    //the value of the variable tbodyNode is the parentNode of the first item in the rows array
    var tbodyNode = rows[0].parentNode;
    
    //remove the first item from the rows array
 rows.shift();
 
    
    //if the value of the lastRow property of the that object is false
 if ( that.lastRow == false ) {
  //the value of the variable totalsRow is the last item in the rows array
  var totalsRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
  //remove the row represented by totalsRow from the tbodyNode
  totalsRow.parentNode.removeChild(totalsRow);
  //remove the last item from the rows array
  rows.pop();  
 }
 

    //the variable isDate is a function with one parameter: value
    var isDate = function ( value ) {
        //the variable d is a new instance of the Date object with a parameter of value
  var d = new Date(value);
        //return true if value can be converted to a date
  return ! isNaN(d);
    }
    //the variable isMoney is a function with one parameter: value
 var isMoney = function ( value ) {
        //the value of the variable m is the replace method of value with the parameters /[$,]/g and an empty string
  var m = value.replace( /[$,]/g, "" );
        //return true if value is a text string that can be turned into a number
  return ! isNaN(m);
    }

    //the value of the variable direction is 1 if the value of the sortUp property of that is true or -1 if it is false
    var direction = ( that.sortUp ) ? 1 : -1;
    
    //sortRows is a function with the parameters rowA and rowB
    var sortRows = function (rowA, rowB) {
        //create the new variables i, textA, textB, valueA, and valueB
  var i, textA, textB, valueA, valueB;
        //create the variable cell
  var cell;

        //the value of the variable cellsA is an array of the td tags from rowA
        var cellsA = rowA.getElementsByTagName("td");
        //create a for loop where i equals 0, the loop runs while i is less than the length of the cellsA array, and i increments by 1 on each loop
  for ( i = 0; i < cellsA.length; i++ ) {
            //the value of cell is the value of the item represented by i in the cellsA array
   cell = cellsA[i];
            //if the value of the className property of cell equals the value of the sortColumn property of that
   if ( cell.className == that.sortColumn ) {
                //the value of valueA is the firstChild nodeValue of  cell
    valueA = cell.firstChild.nodeValue;
                //end the function
    break;
            }
        }

        //the value of the variable cellsB is an array of the td tags from rowB
        var cellsB = rowB.getElementsByTagName("td");
        //create a for loop where i equals 0, the loop runs while i is less than the length of the cellsB array, and i increments by 1 on each loop
  for ( i = 0; i < cellsB.length; i++ ) {
            //the value of cell is the value of the item represented by i in the cellsB array
   cell = cellsB[i];
            //if the value of the className property of cell equals the value of the sortColumn property of that
   if ( cell.className == that.sortColumn ) {
                //the value of valueB is the firstChild nodeValue of cell
    valueB = cell.firstChild.nodeValue;
                //end the function
    break;
            }
        }

        //if valueA and valueB are numbers 
        if ( ! isNaN(valueA) && ! isNaN(valueB) ) {
            //the value of valueA is valueA converted to a number with decimal places
   valueA = parseFloat(valueA);
            //the value of valueB is valueB converted to a number with decimal places
   valueB = parseFloat(valueB);
        //otherwise, if valueA and valueB can be converted to dates
  } else if ( isDate(valueA) && isDate(valueB) ) {
            //the value of valueA is a new date object with the parameter of valueA
   valueA = new Date(valueA);
            //the value of valueB is a new date object with the parameter of valueB
   valueB = new Date(valueB);
        //otherwise, if valueA and valueB are money values
  } else if ( isMoney(valueA) && isMoney(valueB) ) {
            //the value of valueA is valueA converted to a number with decimal places that has the dollar signs and commas replaced with empty strings
   valueA = parseFloat(valueA.replace( /[$,]/g, "" ));
            //the value of valueB is valueB converted to a number with decimal places that has the dollar signs and commas replaced with empty strings
   valueB = parseFloat(valueB.replace( /[$,]/g, "" ));
        }

        //if the value of valueA is less than the value of valueB
        if ( valueA < valueB ) {
            //return -1 multiplied by the value of direction
   return -1 * direction;
        //otherwise if the value of valueB is less than the value of valueA
  } else if ( valueB < valueA ) {
            //return 1 multiplied by the value of direction
   return 1 * direction;
        //otherwise
  } else {
            //return the number 0
   return 0;
        }
    }
    
    //execute the sort method of the rows array with the parameter of the function sortRows
    rows.sort( sortRows );

    //create a for loop where i equals 0, the loop continues as long as the value of i is less than the length of the rows array, and the value of i is incremented each time through the loop
    for ( i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        //execute the appendChild method of tbodyNode with the parameter of the item in the rows array represented by i
  tbodyNode.appendChild( rows[i] );
    }
 
 //if totalsRow exists in this object
 if (totalsRow) {
  //execute the insertBefore method of the tbodyNode with the parameters of totalsRow and rows[rows.length]
  //tbodyNode.insertBefore( totalsRow, rows[rows.length] ); //that doesn't work with internet explorer, so I changed it to the code below
  tbodyNode.appendChild( totalsRow );
 }
}​
```

```css
//if the jsLib object doesn't exist
if ( ! jsLib ) {
    //create a new object named jsLib
 var jsLib = {};
}
//if the event object doesn't exist in the jsLib object
if ( ! jsLib.event ) {
     //create a new object in the jsLib object named event
 jsLib.event = {};
}

//the handlerId property of the event property is 1
jsLib.event.handlerId = 1;

//the add method of the event object takes three parameters: element, type, handler
jsLib.event.add = function (element, type, handler) {
    //if handlerid property of handler doesn't exist
    if (!handler.handlerId) {
        //the handlerId property of handler is the handlerId property of the event property incremented by 1
  handler.handlerId = jsLib.event.handlerId++;
    }
    
    //the value of the variable oldHandlerName is "jsLib_old_" plus  the value of type plus the value of the handlerId property of handler
    var oldHandlerName = "jsLib_old_" + type + "_" + handler.handlerId;
    //the value of the variable newHandlerName is "jsLib_new_" plus the value of type plus the value of the handlerId property of handler
 var newHandlerName = "jsLib_new_" + type + "_" + handler.handlerId;

    //if element has the addEventListener method
    if ( element.addEventListener ) {   
        //the value of the oldHandlerName item within element is the value handler
  element[oldHandlerName] = handler;
         //the value of the newHandlerName item within element is a new event handler
  element[newHandlerName] = function(evt) {
            //use the fixEvent method to standardize the old event handler
   element[oldHandlerName](jsLib.event.fixEvent(evt));
        }
        //add an event listener to element with the parameters type, element[newHandlerName], false
  element.addEventListener( type, element[newHandlerName], false);
        //return a value of true
  return true;    
    //if element has the attachEvent method
    } else if ( element.attachEvent ) { 
         //the value of the oldHandlerName item within element is the value handler
  element[oldHandlerName] = handler;
         //the value of the newHandlerName item within element is a new event handler
  element[newHandlerName] = function() {
            //use the fixEvent method to standardize the old event handler
   element[oldHandlerName](jsLib.event.fixEvent(window.event));
        }
  //attach an event listener with the parameters "on"+type, element[newHandlerName]
        element.attachEvent("on"+type, element[newHandlerName]);
        //return a value of true
  return true;
    }
    //return a value of true
 return false;
}

//the remove method of the event object takes three parameters: element, type, handler
jsLib.event.remove = function (element, type, handler) {
    //the value of the variable oldHandlerName is "jsLib_old_" plus  the value of type plus the value of the handlerId property of handler
 var oldHandlerName = "jsLib_old_" + type + "_" + handler.handlerId;
     //the value of the variable newHandlerName is "jsLib_new_" plus the value of type plus the value of the handlerId property of handler
 var newHandlerName = "jsLib_new_" + type + "_" + handler.handlerId;

    //if element has the removeEventListener property
    if ( element.removeEventListener ) {
        //remove the event listener from the element using the paramters type, element[newHandlerName], false
  element.removeEventListener(type, element[newHandlerName], false);
        //the value of the newHandlerName item within element is null
  element[newHandlerName] = null;
        //the value of the oldHandlerName item within element is null
  element[oldHandlerName] = null;
        //return a value of true
  return true;
    //otherwise if element has the removeEventListener property
    } else if ( element.detachEvent ) {
        //detach the event from the element using the paramters "on"+type, element[newHandlerName] 
  element.detachEvent( "on"+type, element[newHandlerName] );
         //the value of the newHandlerName item within element is null
  element[newHandlerName] = null;
        //the value of the oldHandlerName item within element is null
  element[oldHandlerName] = null;
        //return a value of true
  return true;
    }
 //return a value of false
    return false;
}

//the fixEvent method of the event object takes one parameter: oEvt
jsLib.event.fixEvent = function (oEvt) {
    // if the Event object has already been fixed, exit this method
    if ( oEvt.fixed === true ) return oEvt;

    //the variable evt is an object
    var evt = {};
    //the fixed property of the the evt object is true
 evt.fixed = true;

    //the oEvt property of the evt object is oEvt
    evt.oEvt = oEvt;
    //the type property of the evt object is type property of oEvt 
 evt.type = oEvt.type;

    //if oEvt contains a "target" property
    if ( "target" in oEvt ) {
        //the value of the target property of evt is the value of the target property of oEvt
  evt.target =  oEvt.target;
    //otherwise if oEvt contains a "srcElement" property
 } else if ( "srcElement" in oEvt ) {
        //the value of the target property of evt is the value of the srcElement property of oEvt
  evt.target =  oEvt.srcElement;
    //otherwise
 } else {
        //the value of the target property of evt is the document
  evt.target = document;
    }
    //if the target property of evt is null //the value of the target property of evt is the document
 if ( evt.target == null ) evt.target = document;
    //if the target nodetype property of evt is 3
 if ( evt.target.nodeType == 3 ) {       // Fix Safari "span" problem
        //the value of the target property of evt is the target parentNode property of evt
  evt.target = evt.target.parentNode;
    }

    //if oEvt contains a "timeStamp" property
    if ( "timeStamp" in oEvt ) {
        //the timestamp property of evt equals the timestamp property of oEvt
  evt.timeStamp = oEvt.timeStamp;
    //otherwise
 } else {
        //the timestamp property of evt equals the valueOf method of a new Date object
  evt.timeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
    }

    //the shiftKey property of evt  equals the shiftKey property of oEvt
    evt.shiftKey = oEvt.shiftKey;
    //the ctrlKey property of evt  equals the ctrlKey property of oEvt
 evt.ctrlKey = oEvt.ctrlKey;
    //the altKey property of evt  equals the altKey property of oEvt
 evt.altKey = oEvt.altKey;
    //the value of the metaKey property of evt  is the metaKey property of oEvt if the metaKey property exists or the 
 //ctrlKey property of oEvt if it doesn't
 evt.metaKey = ( "metaKey" in oEvt ) ? oEvt.metaKey : oEvt.ctrlKey;

 //the preventDefault method of evt is 
    evt.preventDefault = function () {
        //if the preventDefault method exists in oEvt
  if ( "preventDefault" in oEvt ) {    // DOM Standard
            //execute the preventDefault method of oEvt
   oEvt.preventDefault();     
        //otherwise if the returnDefault method exists in oEvt
  } else if ( "returnValue" in oEvt) { // IE
            //the returnValue property of oEvt is false
   oEvt.returnValue = false;  
        }
    }
    
    //the stopPropagation method of evt is 
    evt.stopPropagation = function () {
        //if the stopPropagation method exists in oEvt
  if ( "stopPropagation" in oEvt ) {     // DOM Standard
           //execute the stopPropagation method of oEvt
     oEvt.stopPropagation();    
         //otherwise if the cancelBubble method exists in oEvt
  } else if ( "cancelBubble" in oEvt ) { // IE
            //the cancelBubble property of oEvt is true
   oEvt.cancelBubble = true;  
        }
    }
    
    //if the jsLib.event.mouse object and the jsLib.event.mouse.fixMouse method exist
    if ( jsLib.event.mouse && jsLib.event.mouse.fixMouse ) {
        //execute the fixMouse method with the parameters of oEvt and evt
  jsLib.event.mouse.fixMouse( oEvt, evt );
    }
    
    //if the jsLib.event.keyboard object and the jsLib.event.mouse.fixKeys method exist
    if ( jsLib.event.keyboard && jsLib.event.keyboard.fixKeys ) {
        //execute the fixKeys method with the parameters of oEvt and evt
  jsLib.event.keyboard.fixKeys( oEvt, evt );
    }
    
 //return the value of evt
    return evt;
}​
```

```html
//if the jsLib object doesn't exist, create a new object named jsLib 
if ( ! jsLib ) { var jsLib = {}; }
//if the jsLib.dom object doesn't exist, create a new object named jsLib .dom
if ( ! jsLib.dom ) { jsLib.dom = {}; }

//the readyList property of the jsLib.dom object is an empty array
jsLib.dom.readyList = [];

//the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object has a value of false
jsLib.dom.isReady = false;

//the ready method of the jsLib.dom object is a function with one parameter: fn
jsLib.dom.ready = function ( fn ) {
    //if fn is a function
 if ( fn instanceof Function ) {
        //if the value of the jsLib.dom isReady property is true
  if ( jsLib.dom.isReady ) {
            //execute the call method of fn with the parameter document
   fn.call(document);
        //otherwise
  } else {
            //add the value of fn to the end of the readyList array
   jsLib.dom.readyList.push( fn );
        }
    //otherwise
 } else {
        //if the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object is true
  if ( jsLib.dom.isReady ) {
            //while the length of the readList array is greater than 0
   while ( jsLib.dom.readyList.length > 0 ) {
                //the value of fn is the last element in the readList array, which has been removed
    fn = jsLib.dom.readyList.pop();
                //execute the call method of fn with the parameter of document
    fn.call(document);
            }
        }
    }
}

//the readyInit method of the jsLib.dom object is a function 
jsLib.dom.readyInit = function () {
    //if the addEventListener method exists 
 if ( document.addEventListener ) {   // DOM event model
        //attach an event listener to the document with the parameters "DOMContentLoaded" and a function that is defined as
  document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded",
            function () {
                //the value of the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object is true
    jsLib.dom.isReady = true;
                //execute the ready method of the  jsLib.dom object
    jsLib.dom.ready();
            },
            //return a value of false
   false
        );
    //otherwise if the attachEvent method exists
 } else if ( document.attachEvent ) { // IE event model
        //if the doScroll method exists and the value of window equals window.top
        if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && window == window.top ) {   // Are we in an iframe?
            // No, we're not in an iframe. Use doScroll polling to
            // simulate DOMContentLoaded. By Diego Perini at
            // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
            
   //the variable doScrollPoll is a function
   var doScrollPoll = function () {
                //if the value of the isReady property of the jsLib dom object is true, return to the calling function
    if ( jsLib.dom.isReady ) return;
                //try this set of actions
    try {
                    //execute the the doScroll method of the documentElement property with a parameter of "left"
     document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
                //if there is an error, catch the error
    } catch( error ) {
                    //set a timer with the parameters of the doScrollPoll function and a delay time of 0
     setTimeout( doScrollPoll, 0 );
                    //return to the calling function
     return;
                }
                //the value of the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object is true
    jsLib.dom.isReady = true;
                //execute the ready method of the  jsLib.dom object
    jsLib.dom.ready();
            }
            //execute the doScrollPoll function
   doScrollPoll();
        //otherwise
  } else {
            // Yes, we are in an iframe or doScroll isn't supported.
            // Use the onreadystatechange event
            //attach an event to the document with the parameters of "onreadystatechange" and a function that is defined as
   document.attachEvent(
                "onreadystatechange",
                function () {
                    //if the value of the readyState property of the document is "complete"
     if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                        //the value of the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object is true
      jsLib.dom.isReady = true;
                        //execute the ready method of the  jsLib.dom object
      jsLib.dom.ready();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        
        // Use the onload event as a last resort
  //if the attachEvent method exists
        if ( window.attachEvent ) {   
            //execute the attachEvent method with the parameters of onload and a function that is defined as 
   window.attachEvent(
                "onload",
                function () {
                    //the value of the isReady property of the jsLib.dom object is true
     jsLib.dom.isReady = true;
                    //execute the ready method of the  jsLib.dom object
     jsLib.dom.ready();
                }
            );
        }
    }
}

// Call the method that initializes the DOM library
jsLib.dom.readyInit();​
```

Comment: I had to add the 2 CSS files and 3 JS files to the same text areas, BTW

Comment: Can you edit your post and show as only snipped of code which you have troubles with. That will increase readable of your question a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the exact path/location of the images in your code

```
imageNode.src = "arrows_off.png";
```